# Refresh all the page

Tags: html, forms, google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications

I'm working on a Google Sheet file where all the data is hidden (there's a trigger which hides all data when the page is open).

I made a button which calls a side bar html form.
On this html form, the user can insert data and submit the form, then the wanted data is displayed.

I recently added a refresh button on the form. My purpose is to refresh all the page (or the sheet file if it's enough).

Here's my code

**Filter.gs**

```
function refreshh () {
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
}
```

**FormFilter.html**

```
  <!-- ... -->
  <button type="submit"> Submit </button>
  
  <button type="button" onClick="refreshh()"> Refresh </button>
```

I tried to use the flush function which should respond to my need.

I tried "window.location.reload();" but this refresh the side bar form only.

Have you any ideas to correct this issue ?

Comment: Please explain what you expect refresh to accomplish.

Comment: Please share the code in your onOpen() that hides all of the data

Comment: To "refresh" a side bar you might call from client-side the same server-side function that opened the side bar. If you need further help add a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstood.
I want to refresh all the page or at least the sheet file. Not only the side bar form.

Here's the function associated with the onOpen() trigger


`/**
 * Hides all data by default
 */
function hideDatas() {
  for (var k=4; k < sheetDataRange.getValues().length; k++) {
    if (sheet.isRowHiddenByUser(k)) {
      sheet.showRows(k+1);
    }
    sheet.hideRows(k+1);
  }
}`

I resolved my issue. I called again this function when I click on the form button.
However, I could be more optimized to refresh the page and let the trigger hide the data

Comment: If your issue was solved, consider providing an answer explaining how you solved your issue.

Comment: @Iamblichus It's not really solved. I found an alternative.
My purpose is to find a way to refresh the sheet file with an HTML button.
The alternative option I found is to call again, when the button is clicked,  the function called when the sheet file is opened.
But I'm still looking for a way to refresh the entire page/sheet file

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `refresh`?

Comment: I mean reload all the page. Not only the side bar form

Answer (score 0):

This will show hidden sheets:

```
function ShowTheHiddenSheets() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets().forEach(s => {if(s.isSheetHidden()) s.showSheet();})
}
```